# Print sequences with prime sum

Tags: algorithm, permutation, primes

Given an integer `n`, I want to find two permutations of the numbers `1` to `n` (inclusive) such that the sum of numbers from the two permutations at any given index is always prime.

For example:

```
   n = 5

      1 2 3 4 5
      1 5 4 3 2

   n = 8

      1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
      2 1 4 3 8 7 6 5
```

Comment: A detail: in the first exemple, it should be [1 5 4 3 2]. What is the maximum size of n?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: 1 <= N <= 10pow6.   Any possible sequence can be printed.

Answer (score 2):

Construct a bipartite graph on {0,1} x {1...n} such that (0, i) and (1, j) are connected if and only if i+j is prime.

Find a perfect matching using any standard technique, and then produce the sequences so that the matching numbers are at the same index.

Comment: Finding the edges is slow.

Answer (score 2):

Find the smallest number k>=1 such that n+k is prime.

Form pairs: (n,k), (n-1, k+1), ..., (k,n).

If k>1, repeat on the range [1,k].

E.g., n=5: 5+2=7, so we have:

```
5, 4, 3, 2
2, 3, 4, 5
```

Then we repeat for 1.

E.g. n=8: 8+3 = 11, so we have:

```
8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
```

Leaving us with 2:

```
1, 2
2, 1
```

By Bertrand's postulate aka Chebyshev's theorem, for any n>1 there is a prime p s.t. n < p < 2n, and for n=1 we have 1+1=2, so we will always be able to do this.

Comment: This takes O(n)

Comment: Very nice! I like when an application of maths can make the programming easier.

Comment: @Dave Very nice.  Literally most of the work is in writing down the permutations.

Comment: With good primality tests, the rest of the work is polynomial in `log(n)`.  Even with trial division the additional work is `O(sqrt(n))`.

Comment: @btilly Agreed. We don't have to worry about the bad case where k is always close to n, because if k = (n-r) for small r then in the next iteration our range is [1, n-r-1], but we know we won't be able to make a prime > n+1 so our prime will be in the range [n-r,n] and k will be <= r. I.e., at least every other time we'll be cutting the range in at least half.

Comment: @Dave On average `k = O(log(n))`.  If Cramer's conjecture is true, the worst case gaps are bounded above by `O(log(n)^2)`.  That is not proven (it is much stronger than the Riemann hypothesis), but it has been proven that the worst case for `k` is bounded above by `O(n^(5/8))`.

Comment: I get system crash when n goes upto 10 power 6.  What should I do?

Comment: @PrashanthKumar That's impossible to say without seeing your code & knowing what language you're using. I suggest that you pose that as a separate question, where you show your code and the error, and ask for help. Different people will be best able to help with coding issues than with algorithms questions.

Comment: Thanks for the concern...but I figured it out. Thanks for your help too. I have applied the same concept.